# Issues with add_query_arg() not passing a variable

Tags: functions

I'm trying to pass a variable (`$homezip`) to the URL on a new page using `add_query_arg()`, but it's not working for variables although radius works fine.

```
$homezip = $_POST["search"];
$stringzip = esc_url( add_query_arg(
  array(
    'zip' => $homezip,
    'radius' => '70'
  ),'' ));


<form action="/local-concert-listings/<?php echo $stringzip; ?>" method="post">
      <input  id="address" size="5" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" name="search"/>
      <input type="submit" value="go" name="SubmitButton" onclick="codeAddress()" />
</form>
```

I've been trying to turn `$homezip` into a string but nothing works. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The code works fine. Are you sure that `$_POST["search"]` is set?

Comment: Also: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_search_query

Comment: What do you mean by 'set'?

Comment: If the page is loaded and a `search` option is not sent via POST or if it's empty then your code will not do what you expect it to. You need to do validation. Also I wouldn't pass in '' as your url, would it not be better to pass in `esc_url( home_url( '/local-concert-listings/' ) )`?

Comment: How do I check to see if `search` is sent via POST? and when I pass `esc_url( home_url( '/local-concert-listings/' ) )` it breaks the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a GET method and got rid of add_query_arg() function

```
$homezip = $_GET["search"];
<form action="local-concert-listings/" method="get">
        <input  id="address" size="6" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" name="zipcode"/>
         <div style="display:none;">
         <input id="volume" size="1" name="miles" value="70" placeholder="70"></input>
              </div>      
         <input type="submit" value="go" name="SubmitButton" onclick="codeAddress()" />
 </form>
```